# Why is there json_decode($array, TRUE)?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I send a dictionary as JSON to a server. The dictionary contains only 1 key, that is an array of items:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$array = json_decode($request['array']);
```

The value for key 'array' is an array, can't be an object.

So, basically these two methods will return the same thing:

```
$array = json_decode($request['array']);

$array = json_decode($request['array'], TRUE);
```

**Am I right?**

The only use for this method is when you want to convert an object into an array:

```
$array = json_decode($request['object'], TRUE);
```

Why would you ever want to do that?

I mean, I do understand that there might be applications for this but on the other hand it took me a whole day to digest this way of thinking and it still feels like there's a huge mind gap.

This little convenience messes up with the concrete way of parsing data and is just confusing to a newbie like me.

Comment: Well, in many cases working with an associative array is easier than working with a standard class object, that's why.

Comment: If it's easier to work with an associative array then... why are you sending an object in the first place???

Comment: You're not sending an object, you're sending a string formatted as JSON. How you parse that JSON on the server is up to you, and generally speaking associative arrays are often easier to work with than standard class objects.

Comment: If it's generally easier why isn't that the default method? Why is the default method something that is generally harder? Do you see where I'm getting at? And why I see this as an inconsistency?

Comment: I guess it depends, objects aren't really harder to use, but in PHP most of the time you'll work with associative arrays, like superglobals or data structures you create etc. Sometimes you'll create objects, and objects are fine, but a little different. To convert a simple JSON structure into something usable, it's generally more familiar to get an array rather than an object, but maybe you should just read up on the difference between an associative array and stdClass object instead

Answer (score 8):

There's a clear distinction between *arrays* and *objects* in Javascript/JSON. Arrays do not have explicit indices but are numerically indexed, while objects are unsorted and have named properties. By default `json_decode` honours this difference and decodes JSON arrays to PHP arrays and JSON objects to PHP objects (instances of `stdClass`).

However, PHP's arrays *also* happen to support associative indices; so a JSON object could be decoded to either a PHP object *or* a PHP array. You can choose which you prefer with that second parameter to `json_decode`. There's no 100% clear 1:1 mapping between these two different languages here, so there's a preference instead.

Answer (score 6):

Why the true is there, you can understand ,, See the following code below.

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Output will be for the above code:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Comment: err, you haven't actually explained anything here - you've simply illustrated what the OP already stated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply If you use true, i will show in array format and if you dont use, than it will show in